# Im trying to get a users info using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, axios

Im creating a management application where users can input their information such as emails, names, and contacts. Im having trouble finding out how to display the info in a view tab. My frontend is set up but the info isnt being passed in. heres my code.

```
const getUser = async (req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.params

    try {
    
        const user = await User.findById(id)
        if(!user) return res.status(400).send({error: 'User not found'})
        res.json(user)

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

heres my code in the frontend to get the data

```
const getExistingUser = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5500/api/user/${id}`)
        if(res.status === 200) {
           setData({...res.data[0] })
        }
    }
```

here is my mongoose schema for how im setting up getting the data

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

let mgmtSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true},
    contact: { type: Number, required: true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

mgmtSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('mgmt', mgmtSchema);
```

here is the error code im getting

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined}" (type string) at path "_id" for model "mgmt"
at model.Query.exec (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4638:21)
at model.Query.Query.then (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4737:15)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
messageFormat: undefined,
stringValue: '"undefined}"',
kind: 'ObjectId',
value: 'undefined}',
path: '_id',
reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
at new BSONTypeError (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/bson/lib/error.js:41:28)
at new ObjectId (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/bson/lib/objectid.js:65:23)
at castObjectId (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:24:12)
at ObjectId.cast (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:247:12)
at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1180:12)
at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1615:15)
at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1605:15)
at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1582:20)
at cast (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:341:32)
at model.Query.Query.cast (/Users/kobesutton/Desktop/management-system/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:5073:12),
valueType: 'string'

Comment: Please share more information like what is in `const user` & `res.data[0]` or any error message.

Comment: You can `console.log(...)` the variable values and see what is happening.